# How do you write sigmoid function for matrices and vectors?

Tags: notation

I would like to apply the sigmoid (logistic) function:

$\sigma{(x)} = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$

to a vector $\mathbb{R}^n$ or matrix $\mathbb{R}^{m × n}$.

And the question is how to write this function for vectors/matrices. I need it for a scientific publication.

Comment: Oftentimes people simply write $\sigma(\mathbf{x})$ to denote elementwise application of $\sigma$ to the vector or matrix (so if $\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ z\end{bmatrix}$, then $\sigma(\mathbf{x})=\sigma\left(\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ z\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}\sigma(x)\\ \sigma(y) \\ \sigma(z)\end{bmatrix}$ for example). If in doubt, maybe you could just quickly explain the notation you are using.

Comment: Please answer the question, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oftentimes, people simply write $\sigma(\mathbf{x})$ to denote elementwise application of the sigmoid function to a vector or matrix. (For example, the author does it [here](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html), search the page for "vectorizing".) If in doubt, maybe you could just quickly explain the notation you are using.